# getting bad request on tests using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning django rest framework and I'm trying and a test get me a bit nervous, so if someone can help me I would appreciate

my tests.py file:

```
    def test_post_method(self):
        url = '/arvores/'
        self.especie = Especies.objects.create(descricao='Citrus aurantium')
        data = {'descricao':'Laranjeira', 'especie':self.especie.id, 'idade':12}
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

my views.py file:

```
class EspeciesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Especies.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EspeciesSerializer

class ArvoresViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Arvores.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArvoresSerializer
```

serializer.py file:

```
class EspeciesSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Especies
        fields = ['id', 'descricao']


class ArvoresSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Arvores
        fields = ['id','especies', 'descricao', 'idade']
```

and models.py :

```
class Especies(models.Model):
    descricao = models.CharField(verbose_name='Descrição', max_length=255)

class Arvores(models.Model):
    especies = models.ForeignKey(Especies, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    descricao = models.CharField(verbose_name='Descrição', max_length=255)
idade = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

**EDIT**
error on run tests

```
FAIL: test_post_method (api.test.test_arvores.EspeciesTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tikin\Desktop\projetos\api_pomar\api\test\test_arvores.py", line 34, in test_post_method    
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
AssertionError: 400 != 201
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide the complete traceback and error in the question.

Comment: You can inspect the response and there will be some information regarding what went wrong.

Comment: Can you give us the specific error?

Comment: Matthew i put the specific error on edit